# div size by its background or child img

Tags: html, css

I have an image to be fully displayed in the browser window (take a 100% width or 100% of height). I can do this with:

```
    .myClass {
        background-image: 'path/to/image.jpg';
        background-size: contain;
    }

    <div class='myClass'></div>
```

or this:

```
    .myClass img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     }

     <div class='myClass'>
         <img src='path/to/image.jpg'>
     </div>
```

The difficulty is that I need a `div` with size equal to size of displayed image to display content over this image. I can’t set `div` size by its background, as well as I can’t set parent `div` size by its absolutely positioned child `img`.

Of course, I can use js, but I would like to do without it. Any idea how I can do this?